# How to customize Invite Friends Dialog (send lives) in Facebook and make select all friends ability?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm creating flash game for Facebook. I want to ask you how to customize invite friends dialog like this:

[image: app]

I need to make something like in picture:

**1.** *Send lives system;*

**2.** *List of friends who used app (game);*

**3.** *Ability to search for exact friend;*

**4.** *Ability select all friends by clicking 1 button;*

**5.** *List of all friends;*

I misunderstand how to make `Send lives system`. If player for now have 0 lives, he should have ability ask for friends. That pop-up "Invite friends dialog", but how to make that If friend accepted invite It sent live for that user who invited him?

**Custom invite friends dialog**

Also how to make custom invite friends dialog like in picture? I have simple (suggested friends and more results) which looks like:

[image: how it is]

And here is code of that invite friends dialog:

```
<a href="#" onclick="FbRequest('This page is amazing, check it out!','4d5da12cbbb0');">Send Request</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function FbRequest(message, data){
        FB.ui({method:'apprequests',message:message,data:data,title:'Share this site with your friends'},
                function(response){
                        // response.request_ids holds an array of user ids that received the request
                }
        );
}
// typical application initialization code for your site
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : '00000000000000',
        session : {},
        status   : true,
        cookie  : true,
        xfbml   : true
    });
};
</script>
```

**Select all friends**

And how to make that when custom invite friends dialog pop-up all friends (50 as I know max) will be selected already?

I have script which select automatically all friends (50 maximum) from invite friends list. It working by clicking on the orange box 'Firefox' on top left of your screen and select 'Web developing' -> 'Notepad' then paste code and execute It.

Here is code:

```
javascript:elms=document.getElementsByName("checkableitems[]");for (i=0;i<elms.length;i++){if (elms[i].type="checkbox" )elms[i].click()};
```

It select friends sucessfully.

But If I try to use this script in my php file It not working. I'm tring this:

```
window.onload = function () {
window.onload =FbRequest('This page is amazing, check it out!','4d5da07acbbb0');
setTimeout(function() {Select()},9000);
}
function Select() {
var elms = document.getElementsByName("checkableitems[]");for (i=0;i<elms.length;i++){if (elms[i].type="checkbox" )elms[i].click()};
}
```

Could you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi,i am also searching the same thing as you are..did you get any tutorials or any solution for the above question..

Comment: No, no one helped me out....

Comment: Better ask question in parts.

Comment: Hey did you guys got it ? Facebook help is really scarce these days.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Didn't noticed, that the question is old. Maybe it still helps someone.

I never did this myself, but:
You have to implement this yourself by using:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/friendlist?locale=de_DE
To get the list of friends.

Then you can send a request to a list of users:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2?locale=de_DE
(search for "Sending requests to specific lists of friends")

**Edit:**
There is also a tutorial about how to do this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/v2.2?locale=de_DE

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this too, The only thing I've found is Facebook's own tutorial here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/v2.3